# DataGrid Row Header Templates and Row Validation issues

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I have a WPF application, using MVVM design pattern with Entity Framework. In this application I have a Datagrid, that has has row validation and that works just fine. Cells have red border and the Datagrid Row Header has a red ! in it, just what I want.

I then want to be able to doubleclick on the Row Headers to perform some actions, so I have the following to bind a event to my ViewModel

```
<DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ContentControl >
            <Label Content="   ">
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDoubleClick">
                        <cmd:EventToCommand 
                        Command="{Binding Main.SomeCommand, Source={StaticResource Locator}}" 
                        CommandParameter="{Binding Path=SelectedItem, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGrid}}"/>
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            </Label>
        </ContentControl>
    </DataTemplate>
</DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
```

Adding this now removes the red ! on the row header indicating an error in that row.

I cannot now work out how to have both the displaying of a error in the row validation as well as having my item to add an Interaction Trigger to to bind a command on.

Whatever I add in the way of custom Style Triggers or custom DataGrid RowValidationErrorTemplates, it is overridden by my RowHeaderTemplate and I cannot work out how to incorporate the two.

How can I have both an error indication and an Interaction Trigger on a Datagrid Row Header?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, somewhat.

As per http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30905/WPF-DataGrid-Practical-Examples#validation

Create a style

```
    <Style x:Key="RowStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>
                <Setter Property="ToolTip"
          Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},
                 Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

Add to the datagrid

```
<DataGrid.RowValidationRules>
    <local:RowDataInfoValidationRule ValidationStep="UpdatedValue" />
</DataGrid.RowValidationRules>
```

and

```
RowStyle="{StaticResource RowStyle}"
```

and

```
public override ValidationResult Validate(object value,
                    CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        BindingGroup group = (BindingGroup)value;

        StringBuilder error = null;
        foreach (var item in group.Items)
        {
            // aggregate errors
            IDataErrorInfo info = item as IDataErrorInfo;
            if (info != null)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(info.Error))
                {
                    if (error == null)
                        error = new StringBuilder();
                    error.Append((error.Length != 0 ? ", " : "") + info.Error);
                }
            }
        }

        if (error != null)
            return new ValidationResult(false, error.ToString());

        return ValidationResult.ValidResult;
    }
```

End result is the whole row is marked as invalid on the entire row level

I would still like to be able to just effect the Row Headers only, so I will still accept an answer to that.